# How to resolve a named instance from a static class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, ioc-container, autofac

Does anyone have any idea about what i doing wrong?

I have a such static class:

```
public static class ApplicationContainer
{
    private static ContainerBuilder builder = null;
    private static IContainer container = null;

    public static void Create()
    {
        builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterInstance(new Repository<Log>(RepositoryType.Main))
            .As<IRepository<Log>>().SingleInstance()
            .Named("Log", typeof(Repository<Log>));

        container = builder.Build();
    }     

    public static IContainer Container()
    {
        if (container != null) return container;
        throw new Exception("Container is not ready.");
    }
}
```

In Global.asax.cs of my MVC application i have:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        ApplicationContainer.Create(); 

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

And now about problem: how can i to resolve named instance from a container?

```
public class DefaultLogger : ILogger
{
    ApplicationContainer.Container().Resolve("Log", typeof(Repository<Log>);// <--- does not work
}
```

But when ApplicationContainer class is not static, resolving from container works very good.
I use autofac 2.2.4.

Comment: Yes, I have a pretty good idea about what you are doing wrong: You are using a static Service Locator: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx Don't do that.

Comment: That said, however, *how* does it not work? Does it throw an Exception? Which one? The "Container is not ready." Exception?

Comment: You'll definitely need to post the exception in order to get an accurate answer to this.

Comment: maybe ApplicationContainer.Container().Resolve("Log", typeof(IRepository<Log>)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot compile this code since you are missing a closing ')' for your `.Resolve(...)` call.

That said, have you looked at the [Autofac ASP.Net integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AspNetIntegration) modules?

Comment: You forget to mention that such declaration inside DefaultLogger is invalid at all (: